# Assigning properties to array gives length 0 in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

We can assign properties to an array, but why the length in this case is 0?
See the code attached

```
var person = []
person.fname = "Mr. Brown"
person.lname = "White"
person.length // gives 0 why?
```

Comment: yes. that's right. what do you expect from an [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/)?

Comment: Only indexed porperties are counted. Attaching properties with random names is allowed because arrays are objects but arrays do not actually do anything with those.

Comment: Yes this is expected behaviour https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#relationship_between_length_and_numerical_properties

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [the specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-properties-of-array-instances-length):

> The "length" property of an Array instance is a data property whose value is always numerically greater than the name of every configurable own property whose name is an array index.

and

> An integer index is a String-valued property key that is a canonical numeric String (see 7.1.21) and whose numeric value is either +0 or a positive integral Number ≤ (253 - 1). An array index is an integer index whose numeric value i is in the range +0 ≤ i < (232 - 1).

---

Arrays are designed to hold a ordered sequence of values represented by integer properties (`0`, `1`, `2`, etc).

While they are objects and so you can shove any property you like on them, that isn't what they are designed for.

The `length` is designed to count the ordered sequence of values. It isn't a count of every property of any name.

Answer (score -1):

Array stores elements. If you want to call person.name= "Mr.Brown"
You can actually implement it by:

```
//Initialize the variable
let person = [];

//Specify the object that will be pushed to the Array 'Person'
let objectToPush = {name: 'Mr. Brown'};

//Push the object
person.push(objectToPush);

//Get Length
console.log(person.length); //<--- Will return 1;

//Call the name property inside the object
console.log(person[0].name); //<-- returns 'Mr.Brown'
```